# Horizontal Card with 2 column and different height

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the 2 columns of the card where the left side would be the image and the right side would be the text. But I want to make the 'right column' height 3/4 less than the 'image column' height and position in the middle of the 'left column' and the button position is always at the bottom of the right card (fix position) even the text in the card is not many.

I have tried the code below but it doesn't meet what I need

https://jsfiddle.net/n0p4tbo9/

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-horizontal">
                    <div class="img-square-wrapper">
                        <img class="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x180" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <button>Learn More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.card-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

I expect the output should be like this picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw1yH.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `display: grid;` instead of `display: flex;`. Grids are way better than flex for positioning items both horizontally and vertically.

Here's a fork of your fiddle as an exemple: https://jsfiddle.net/0hf51xaL/